# Two bootstrap carousels next to each other won't align

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get two bootstrap carousels to align with each other so they are in the same row. When on a xs or sm device they carousels are stacked properly like I want them, but on md and lg devices the carousels need to sit next to each other, not vertically or offset like they are now.

Any idea why this may be happening? I originally thought it was a padding issue but I can't seem to adjust it properly.

The site can be found here: http://mylomatt.mylio.com/stackoverflow.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of link rotting and the URL is unreachable even on the archive.org .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the `<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 carouselpadding">` (the div wrapping your "Welcome to Mylio Support" carousel) out of the larger wrapper class

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
```

So that it looks like

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-push-6"> 
    <!-- first carousel -->
</div>
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 carouselpadding"> 
    <!-- second carousel -->
</div>
```

I think you meant for them to be separate, but because the second carousel was actually contained in a wrapper div for the first, any styles you applied to the first would also cascade down into the second, which is difficult to fix if not expected.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a small/stupid mistake but it fixed it instantly. Thank you!!!